# Prove $p=2$ for a linear $[p^m+2, p^m-1, 4]$ MDS code

Tags: coding-theory

Consider the code $L$ with size $n=q+2$ and dimension $k=q-1$, where $q=p^m$ and $m$ is an integer.

I have to prove that $p=2$ if $L$ is an MDS code.

So we assume that $L$ is MDS. 
Thus by definition of MDS, $L$ is a $[n, k, n-k+1]=[p^m+2, p^m-1, p^m+2-(p^m-1)+1]=[p^m+2, p^m-1, 4]$-code.

If it is correct, I am unsure on how to proceed. There is a theorem in my  notes that states that if a nontrivial $[n,k]$-code exists, then $n-q+1 \le k \le q-1 => (p^m+2)-(p^m)+1 \le p^m - 1 \le (p^m)-1 => 3 \le p^m - 1  => 4 \le p^m$.

This is satisfied by $p=2$ for $m>1$, however why can we assume that $m>1$? If not then it could be satisfied by $p=4$ for all $m$, but $4$ is not prime.

I am not sure this is the right method. Any help is appreciated, thank you! Does the MDS conjecture have a role in this? Could I still use that theorem?

Comment: $p$ is supposed to be a _prime_ and so $p=6$ is not a case that needs to be considered.

Comment: Thank you! Why does p need to be a prime? @DilipSarwate

Comment: Generally, $p$ is used tp denote the _characteristic_ of a finite field, and it must be a prime number. The cardinality of the field is often denoted by $q$, and whenever people write $q=p^m$, the _convention_ is that $p$ must be a prime. But even if this convention is not followed, there must be _some_ prime $p^\prime$ that is the characteristic of the field and _it must_ be the case that $q$ is a _power_ of $p^\prime$ , say $q=(p^\prime)^{mn}$ and so $q=p^m$ implies that $p=(p^\prime)^n$. Regardless of whether $p$ is a prime or a _power_ of some other prime $p^\prime$, $p$ cannot equal $6$.

Answer (score 0):

By duality we prove that there doesn't exist any $[p^m+2,3,p^m]_{p^m}$ MDS code with $p\ne 2$. Consider its generator matrix in standard form:
$$
G=(I_3|A)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 &1&1&\cdots&1\\
0 & 1 & 0 &* & * &\cdots & *\\
0 & 0 & 1 &* & * &\cdots & *
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(Every $k$ columns of the generator matrix of a $[n,k]$ MDS code must be linearly independent. Hence the columns of $A$ mustn't contain any zero, otherwise such a column will be the linear combination of certain $k-1$ columns from the first $k$ columns. Furthurmore we can suppose that the first row of $A$ are $1$, since multiplying a coordinate with a nonzero constant does not harm MDS.)

Still, from the fact that every $k$ columns of $G$ are linearly independent, we can see that the second and third rows of $A$ must be a permutation of all elements from $\mathbb{F}^\times$, i.e. mustn't have two elements of the same value. By reordering we suppose that
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\theta^0 & \theta^1 &\cdots &\theta^{p^m-2}\\
\theta^{\pi(0)} & \theta^{\pi(1)} & \cdots &\theta^{\pi(p^m-2)}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\theta$ is the generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}^\times$, and $\pi:\{0,\ldots,p^m-2\}\to \{0,\ldots,p^m-2\}$ a permutation. Again the linear independence of $(1,0,0),(1,\theta^i,\theta^{\pi(i)}),(1,\theta^j,\theta^{\pi(j)})$ implies that $\theta^{\pi(i)-i}\ne \theta^{\pi(j)-j}$. Hence $\{\pi(i)-i\}_{i=0}^{p^m-2}=\{0,1,\ldots,p^m-2\}$ (considered $\bmod (p^m-1)$). Now we sum up all elements of the two sets:
$$
0=\sum i-\sum i=\sum pi(i)-\sum i=\sum_{a\in \{\pi(i)-i\}} a
\equiv \sum_{a\in\{0,\ldots,p^m-2\}} a=\frac12(p^m-2)(p^m-1)\pmod{(p^m-1)}.$$
If $p\ne 2$, then $p^m-1$ is even and $\gcd(p^m-1,p^m-2)=1$. Hence
$$
(p^m-1)\nmid\frac12(p^m-2)(p^m-1).
$$
Contradiction. Therefore we must have $p=2$.